# Develop service or deamon for mono using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, mono, raspberry-pi3

I want the equivalent of a Windows service running on a Raspberry PI3 and i want to develop it using Mono. (the program must process an audio stream)

I did install Monodevelop on my Linux, but can i develop the same deamon just on my Windows using good old VS2015? And if so, what tools do i need?

Thanks for getting me on track.

Comment: A simple answer should be you shouldn't. Visual Studio is not for Mono. Use MonoDevelop as it avoids most other issues.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i want to know Is it really impossible to use Visual Studio (on Windows) to develop a Mono application. As i understand from you, this is impossible.

Comment: it is possible but I never recommend it, as you will meet miserable issues afterward, which a first time user will be puzzled.